# How to speed up iterations over rows of a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Tried iterrows() very slow, read elsewhere zip would be better, but it is still very slow.

I tried to search through rows of a dataframe, generate some stats to fill in two new dataframe.

Any suggestion to speed-up the searching through rows of dataframe?

**Code snippets:**

```
for index,date,stocknum in zip(stockpicks.index.values,stockpicks.date.values,stockpicks.stocknum.values):

        stock=readStockPrice(stocknum)
        if stock.empty:
            return print("error - empty frame")
        stock=stock.ix[trading_days]
        stockprice=stock.Close.values
        p0_date=trading_days.get_loc(date)


        p0=stockprice[p0_date]
        stock_pct_change={('d'+str(d)):stockprice[p0_date+d]/p0*100.0 if (p0_date+d)< len(trading_days) else np.nan for d in days }

        b0=hsi[p0_date]
        benchmark_pct_change={('d'+str(d)):hsi[p0_date+d]/b0*100.0 if (p0_date+d)< len(trading_days) else np.nan for d in days }

        for d in days:
            stock_analysis.loc[index,'d'+str(d)]=stock_pct_change['d'+str(d)]
            benchmark_analysis.loc[index,'d'+str(d)]=benchmark_pct_change['d'+str(d)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem appears can be vectorized completely. Iteration and indexing like you are doing is the slowest possible way.

```
In [6]: df = DataFrame(np.random.randint(-5,5,size=20).reshape(5,4),columns=list('abcd'),index=date_range('20130101',periods=5))+50.0

In [7]: df.pct_change()
Out[7]: 
                   a         b         c         d
2013-01-01       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
2013-01-02  0.108696  0.108696  0.102041  0.086957
2013-01-03 -0.058824 -0.039216 -0.074074 -0.060000
2013-01-04  0.104167  0.081633 -0.020000  0.000000
2013-01-05 -0.075472 -0.113208  0.061224 -0.021277

[5 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: jeff, tks for your answer.. however, you might have missed the focus of my problem. my code is not about to calculate the pct-change of a matrix of stock quotes, it first has to search thro the stockpicks df for the stock and dates of interest, retrieve the concerned stock quotes from stored csv, and calculate the pct_change in days [1,2,5,10,20,30...250]. so, i have to iterate the rows of stockpicks (searching) and indexing into stock prices of concerns.